# how to open a different plugin, when open a different perspective to the same file on GEF

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I'm develop an project with **RCP + GEF**, which creates a file based on **GEF Logic example**   .

I have two plugins:

- one for design and edit the network
- one for visualize in real time the network operation..

how can I do for when i choose the perspective open the correct plugin?

Each plugin works correctly when i open the file with him, but i dont know how can i do it automatically when i chose the perspective.

My perspectives looks like this:

```
public class DesignPerspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

public static final String ID = "mailteste.DesignPerspective";

public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    layout.setFixed(true);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(true);
    addFastViews(layout);
    layout.addView("org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.18f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
    layout.addView("org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline", IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.8f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);     
    layout.addView("org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.5f, "org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline");
    //layout.addStandaloneView(IPageLayout.ID_OUTLINE, true, IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.76f,IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);  
}

private void addFastViews(IPageLayout layout) {
}
```

Best Regards
Alex

Answer (score 1):

could you be clear on what you are looking for? I understand you have two plugins and you have on fixed perspective ( in which plugin?)

Comment: i have one RCP aplication with two GEF plugins.

one for design network and one for visualize in real time the network operation..

I'm looking for a way to automatically open file with diferent pluging when i choose de perspective..